# How to preserve button-click functionality when dragging & dropping?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a FlowLayoutPanel with several buttons inside, they start programs when clicked. I want to be able to rearrange the buttons inside this FlowLayoutPanel, so I tried implementing drag&drop functionality for the buttons.

I add buttons during runtime to the FlowLayoutPanel with this code:

```
button.Click += delegate ( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
   Process.Start( someExePath );
};

button.MouseDown += delegate ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {
   button.DoDragDrop( button, DragDropEffects.Move );
};
```

As soon as I add the MouseDown delegate to the button, I can't press the button to start an application anymore, instead the Drag&Drop begins. How do I fix it?
My main goal is to be able to rearrange buttons inside the FlowLayoutPanel (preferably with drag&drop) while still being able to start applications by clicking on these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the MouseMove event instead:

```
private void button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
    button.DoDragDrop(button, DragDropEffects.Move);
  }
}
```